# Bean creation exception - Spring integration and jms

Tags: maven, spring-integration, tomcat6, noclassdeffounderror, spring-jms

I am facing a problem where i have spring dependency in my pom.xml for spring integration. mvn clean install is successful but when i start tomcat i am facing the below error. I see the jar in the lib folder. please find the pom.xml as well.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsSendingMessageHandler#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.integration.jms.DynamicJmsTemplate] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSException
```

.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-jms</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: did you have this jar in the lib folder

   <dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0</version>
   </dependency>

Comment: No, it is not there in the lib folder. But spring integration jms jar is not enough?

Comment: this is the JMS API and it need to be in the lib folder and if it is not there this means spring integration jms jar is not enough

Comment: you are talking about the lib folder of the application or tomcat ? this jar can be in tomcat lib folder, have you verified ? if you talk about the lib folder of your application you can add this dependency but normally this dependency is provided